# Security permissions for one security group on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I had a security group and a user who only had access to that group. He had the right to delete and add IP addresses to the inbound rules. But recently it stopped working. When I request `RevokeSecurityGroupIngress` or `AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress`, I get a response:

> You are not authorized to perform this operation

`decode-authorization-message` shows that aws: Resource is needed "* / *", but I need a specific resource.

Answer (score 0):

Check the account you are using to RevokeSecurityGroupIngress permissions.
It might be that permission to perform that operation on your account has been disabled.